# Use action_done function to perform stock move?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-7, openerp-8

I'm trying to call `action_done()` twice to perform two stock moves:

- move old_product_id from source to distination
- move new product_id from distination to source

How to pass `res{}` dictionary to function `action_done(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None)` 
which perform stock move, and what should it return?

```
 class my_class(osv.osv):
  ...
  ...
 def action_move(self, cr , uid,  res, context=None)
    if context is None:
        context= {}
    move_obj = self.pool.get('stock.move')
    res1 = {
          'product_id': old_product_id,
          'location_id': location_id,
          'location_dest_id': location_dest_id,
          'product_uom_qty': product_qty,
          }
    res2 = {
          'product_id': new_product_id,
          'location_id': location_dest_id,
          'location_dest_id': location_id,
          'product_uom_qty': product_qty,
          }
    move_obj.action_done(self,cr, uid, res, context=context)
    move_obj.action_done(self,cr, uid, res2, context=context)
    return ????
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have not yet created at any time record "stock.move". You must first create the "stock.move", then keep the id of the stock move and send in the action done. Something like this:

```
move_obj.action_done (self, cr, uid, beef, context = context)

move_obj.action_done (self, cr, uid, stock_move_res._d, context = context)
```